# calling another function inside IVOR4 Handler (External Interrupt) - NXP

Tags: assembly, powerpc

Here is my question,

Can i do function call inside IVOR4 handler (Prologue and Epilogue ) in MPC5777C?  similar to this Machine_Check_Handler call ?

```
e_lis r0, Machine_check_handler@h
e_or2i r0, Machine_check_handler@l
mtlr r0 # Store LR
```

Idea is to calculate preemption time in External Interrupts, by adding Stop Watch start and End in Prologue and Epilogue section

if it is possible, share sample code which shows function calling in Prologue/Epilogue handler.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? 1) Call an existing machine check handler from other code? 2) Write a machine check handler that simply calls some function? 3) Write a machine check handler that calls an existing machine check handler? By the way: Your code example does not call any function at all.

Comment: Please read the tag info before adding a tag. Question to you, when is the [Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info) tag to be used?

Comment: After reading Guy Coder's comment, I also added the "PowerPC" tag. Questions tagged with "assembly" should always be tagged with the CPU type.